# Array prototype repeater function wrong behaviour

Tags: javascript

I have this simple fun:

```
Array.prototype.arrayRepeat = function(value, times) {  
  for (var x=0;x<times;x++) this[x]=value;
}
```

Then I have:

```
var errs=[];
errs.arrayRepeat([],10);
```

And when I add a new value to item 3 (for example)

```
errs[3].push ("hello")
```

I see how the 10 'errs' items  has a "hello" value.

I don't understand why. Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED:

I want to have an array of arrays. I add 'hello' to `errs[3]` because I want to have: `errs[3]= ["hello"]`.  Later maybe I wanted : `errs[3]=["hello","good-bye"]`, so I'l write `errs[3].push("goodbye");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the arrayRepeat function to look like this:

```
Array.prototype.arrayRepeat = function(value, times) {  
  for (var x=0; x < times; x++) this[x] = value.slice();
}
```

Comment: You should only do this if `value` is an array. `err.arrayRepeat(4, 10);` will get an error when you try to slice the number.

Answer (score 1):

because the arrays in errs share the same reference.
when you do

```
errs.arrayRepeat([],10);
```

the array is "copied" by reference, so when one is modified, all the other are.

Comment: your logic should be if the value parameter type is "object" create a new instance on each iteration

Answer (score 1):

Lets rewrite it a little.

```
a = [];
errs.arrayRepeat(a, 10);
```

Now `errs` hold a **reference** to `a` in each position.

You then do `errs[3].push('hello')` which is the same as `a.push('hello')`

Because every element in `errs` **is** `a` you get this result.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the same reference to each item in errs, so when you add an item to that array, every reference to that array is seeing the item.

An easy way to do a deep copy of the value:

```
Array.prototype.arrayRepeat = function(value, times) {  
    for (var x=0;x<times;x++) this[x]=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method works fine for an array of numbers, strings or boolean values,

but it is only creating one array for all the indexes.

Check for an object before you repeat.

```
Array.repeater= function(val, len){
    var A= [], 
    check=typeof val== 'object' && val.constructor;

    while(len--){
        if(check){
            val= new val.constructor(val);
        }
        A.push(val);
    }
    return A;
}

//test object

var B= Array.repeater(new Date(2015, 3, 14), 10);
B[3].setDate(16);
B.join('\n')

/*  returned value: (String)
Tue Apr 14 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT-0400(Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Apr 14 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT-0400(Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Apr 14 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT-0400(Eastern Standard Time)
Thu Apr 16 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT-0400(Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Apr 14 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT-0400(Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Apr 14 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT-0400(Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Apr 14 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT-0400(Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Apr 14 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT-0400(Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Apr 14 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT-0400(Eastern Standard Time)
Tue Apr 14 2015 00: 00: 00 GMT-0400(Eastern Standard Time)
*/
without the object check, every item would mirror the changed date
```